# Polymer: flashes of white screen when page loads

Tags: javascript, polymer, jekyll, web-component, github-pages

I'm currently working on the web-site using `Polymer`, `Jekyll` and `Github pages`. But I'm facing one big issue. When switching between pages there is a white screen showing every time, which is not correct behavior. I would like to always see the header section and left menu (without flash) even when switching between the pages.

The web-site is not [vulcanized](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) yet (there were another issues with that), so it is not very fast, but this should not be a reason. I was playing with the imports in `<head>` section and scripts, but nothing helps. Seems that the page actually renders only after `DomContentLoaded` event.

Any suggestions?

The web-site can be checked on [this url](http://yunikov.com) and the source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/yyunikov/yyunikov.github.io).

Comment: I was confused at first because on Chrome 41 (OS X), I didn't see any issues. FF 34 & 35 as well as Safari 7 do show a brief FOUC, though. Have you tried loading the web components in the `<head>`?

Comment: Strange. I have this issue on Chrome 40 and Firefox 35 on Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8. Yes, I've tried to load them all in `<head>`, but it does not help really. I've just committed those changes where all components imports are in `<head>`. So you can check it now.

Comment: Moving it to the `<head>` worked for me in FF and Safari - no more unstyled article text on load. The screen is white briefly, but that's inevitable. Try emptying your cache if you cannot see a difference.

Comment: Yes, I see it fixed FOUC in FF. Thanks. But actually the main problem is that the screen is white briefly. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: FF35 / ubuntu 14.04 we have a warning in the console `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create webcomponents.min.js:14`. But no warning in Chromium.

Comment: To be honest, I think the speed is perfectly acceptable, and a very brief white screen is normal as well. You even get very high marks on [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyunikov.com%2F&tab=desktop). If this really bothers you, I would start with that vulcanization thing, because right now, Polymer causes about 35 separate requests for templates and such. But in the end, there is a performance ceiling, because the technology you chose depends on Javascript to transform your markup before it can be displayed. No way around that.

Comment: @David Jacquel, I see that too. But the warning itself is in the `webcomponents.min.js`. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: @YuriyYunikov no idea.

Comment: @janfoeh thanks for your help. I will try to do vulcanization and see if that will help. But if you can take a look at [Polymer Web-site](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html), they don't have such flashing of white screen at all when switching between html pages, so I'm wondering is there anything left I've missed.

Comment: @DavidJacquel it's not important in this context, I would ignore it. Yuriy — the Polymer website feels faster because they don't do full page loads when you navigate between pages - they use AJAX to load the new pages and modify your URL bar with the help of the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to make it look like you went from page A to page B. The term for this kind of thing is [Single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: @janfoeh thanks a lot for your answer! Now it seems to be clear. You can post your answer from all comments as I think it is the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the transition when navigating between pages — the Polymer website feels faster because they don't do full page loads. Instead, they use AJAX to load the new pages and modify your URL bar with the help of the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to make it look like you went from page A to page B. The term for this kind of thing is [Single-page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).